# Append a dynamicaly (newly) created element in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dynamic, append

I'm trying to append an element dynamically in a recursive manner, i.e :

I have an anchor tag with class "request-get", onclick of this anchor tag I append a div with several anchor tags having the same class name "request-get" and divs to append when clicking on the last created anchor tags : here's my code

NB : The ajax call works fine, I get all the data after click event of the newly created anchor tags but I don't get the reference of the newly created Divs

```
$(document).on("click", ".request-get", function (event) {
    var request = new RequestModule.AjaxRequestBuilder(this).build();
    var child = $(this).data('target');
    var childDocument = $(document).find(child);
    console.log(childDocument);
    request.call({
        success: function (response) {
            $(child).empty();
            console.log($(child));
            for (var i in response) {

                var a = $('<a/>', { href: "" })
                            .attr('id', response[i].code)
                            .attr('class', 'request-get child')
                            .attr('data-id', response[i].id)
                            .attr('data-controller', 'objectif')
                            .attr('data-controller-suffix', 'children')
                            .attr('data-method', 'get')
                            .attr('data-target', '#details_' + response[i].code)
                            .attr('data-toggle', 'collapse')
                            .css('display', 'block')
                            .text(response[i].code+' - '+response[i].intitule);

                var div = $('<div/>', { id: 'details_' + response[i].code })
                            .attr('class', 'details collapse child');


                $(child).append(a);
                $(child).append(div);

            }
        },

        error: function (response) {

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by `don't get the reference of the newly created Divs`?  What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be using the wrong variable as you are using the `child` variable instead of the `childElement` one

Comment: `childDocument`*

Comment: even when i print childDocument, it's and Empty Javascript Object, there is no reference to it !

Comment: You may try directly `var child = $($(this).data('target'));`

Answer (score 0):

Your newly append elements don't have same class. You are providing "request-get-objectif" instead of "request-get"

Comment: that was the last update of my code, i was going to try something else and posted the wrong code ! Sorry, thanks for the answer